# Calling GTK_MAIN under Pthread(secondary thread) in C code

Tags: c, gtk, glib

This is in my continuation of GTK understanding::

Is it right to call GTK_MAIN() under pthread from Main?? sample code ::

from **main** i call **dispInit(argc, argv);** from which i call **g_thread_create(main_callback, NULL, FALSE, NULL);**

** also i have not included g_idle_add in this code..this is just a reference code.

Please guide

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
//#include "dispimage.h"
#include <windows.h>
#define sleep(n) Sleep(1000 * n)
GtkWidget* window;
void dispInit(int argc, char* argv[]);
void dispInfoPage(char* fileName, int duration);


gpointer main_callback(gpointer data)
{
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}

void dispInit(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gdk_threads_init();
    gdk_threads_enter();
    printf("Initializing the display library\n");
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_resize(GTK_WINDOW(window), 640, 480);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 640, 480);
    gtk_widget_realize( window );
    gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);
    g_thread_create(main_callback, NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    gdk_threads_leave();
}

void dispInfoPage(char* fileName, int duration)
{
    int index;
    gdk_threads_enter();
    printf("Initializing dispInfoPage\n");
    destroyWidget();
    printf("Initializing dispInfoPage1\n");
    GtkWidget *image;
    image = gtk_image_new_from_file(fileName);
    printf("Initializing dispInfoPage2\n");
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), image);
    gtk_widget_show(image);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    printf("Initializing dispInfoPage4\n");
    printf("Initializing dispInfoPage5\n");
    gdk_threads_leave();
    printf("Initializing dispInfoPage6\n");
}

void destroyWidget()
{
    GList *children, *iter;
    struct WidgetsAlive *temp, *prev, *next, *depTemp;
    children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(window));
    for(iter = children; iter != NULL; iter = g_list_next(iter)){
        gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(window),GTK_WIDGET(iter->data));
        printf("Deleting Widget\n");
    }
    g_list_free(iter);
    g_list_free(children);

}


int dispTextPage(char* fileName, int isJustifyCenter)
{
    int index;
    GtkWidget *textv;
    GdkWindow *textv_window;
    GdkPixmap *pixmap = NULL;
    GtkTextBuffer *textBuffer;
    gdk_threads_enter();
    GdkColor color;
    char debugBuf[128] = { '\0' };
    char newfName[100]={'\0'};
    char ext[4]={'\0'};
    char temp[100]={'\0'};
    int i;
    FILE * fd;
    destroyWidget();
    textBuffer = gtk_text_buffer_new(NULL);
    textv = gtk_text_view_new_with_buffer(textBuffer);
    gtk_text_view_set_left_margin(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), 22);
    gtk_text_view_set_right_margin(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), 20);
    gtk_text_view_set_pixels_above_lines(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv),1);
    gtk_text_view_set_wrap_mode(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), GTK_WRAP_CHAR);
    if (isJustifyCenter == 1)
    {
        gtk_text_view_set_justification(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
    }
    else
    {
        gtk_text_view_set_justification(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), GTK_JUSTIFY_LEFT);
    }
    gtk_text_view_set_editable(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), FALSE);
    gtk_text_view_set_cursor_visible(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv), FALSE);
    printf("tttt0");
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), textv);
    printf("tttt1");
    textv_window = gtk_text_view_get_window (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (textv),
                                           GTK_TEXT_WINDOW_TEXT);
    gdk_color_parse ("#68604d", &color);
    pixmap = gdk_pixmap_create_from_xpm ((GdkDrawable *) textv_window, NULL,
                                       &color, fileName);
    gdk_window_set_back_pixmap (textv_window, pixmap, FALSE);
    g_object_unref(pixmap);

    textBuffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textv));

    gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (textBuffer, "Red", "foreground", "Red", NULL);
    gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (textBuffer, "RedBold","foreground", "Red",NULL);
      gtk_text_buffer_create_tag(textBuffer, "gray_bg", "background", "gray", NULL);
      gtk_text_buffer_create_tag(textBuffer, "italic",  "style", PANGO_STYLE_ITALIC, NULL);
      gtk_text_buffer_create_tag(textBuffer, "bold","weight", PANGO_WEIGHT_BOLD, NULL);
    gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (textBuffer, "RedFontWeight", "weight", 1000,NULL);
    gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (textBuffer, "RedBoldFontWeight","weight", 1000,NULL);
    gtk_widget_show(textv);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gdk_threads_leave();
    return index;
}

void *fsmThread_RunFunction()
{
    int pollMsgRetVal = -1;
    printf("Now enter into for image");
    dispInfoPage("../images/givefp.gif",1);
    sleep(5);
    dispInfoPage("../images/bootup.gif",1);
    sleep(5);
    dispInfoPage("../images/givefp.gif",1);
    sleep(5);
    dispInfoPage("../images/bootup.gif",1);
    sleep(5);
    printf("Now enter into for disptext");
    dispTextPage("",0);
    printf("Now exit for disptext");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GThread *fsmThreadId;
    GError *error = NULL;
    g_thread_init(NULL);
    dispInit(argc, argv);
    dispInfoPage("../images/bootup.gif",1);
    sleep(5);
    printf("Now creat ethread ");
    fsmThreadId = g_thread_create(fsmThread_RunFunction,NULL,TRUE,&error);
    if (error) {
      fflush(stderr);
      exit(1);
    }
    g_thread_join(fsmThreadId);
    sleep(2);

    printf("ENd of main");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: GTK functions should only be called by the main thread.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : this code has that error..which has been fixed with calling G_IDLE_ADD ..But my doubt is is it advisable call GTK_MAIN n a secondary thread

Comment: It is forbidden to call `gtk_main` outside of the main thread.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Reference, please. AFAIK GTK doesn't care **which** thread you call `gtk_main` (and other GTK functions), as long as you consistently do it from **the same** thread.

Comment: Google gives several, e.g. http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness ; STFW for `gtk_main thread`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That link clearly defines "main thread" as "thread running `gtk_main`", so it would be impossible to "call `gtk_main` outside of the main thread". Whether `gtk_main` is called from the main C thread (the thread that executes C `main()`) or from another thread is irrelevant as long as all GTK functions (with the exception of `g_idle_add`) are consistently called from that thread.

Comment: @user4815162342: Can you post that as your answer so that i can accept that

Comment: I've now done so, with the link to the docs and additional details.

Comment: @user4815162342 :: well thats a awsome explanation.But i have a strange performence in our GTK application..it runs very well in our Lenny(debian 5) but in squeeze (debiab 6) it runs well fro days but suddenly we see that our application GUI sudddenly fades out with white screen where we are able to see only the borders of button in the screen..still not able to find any clues on that...what could be approach for debugging the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer: yes, you can call `gtk_main()` from a thread other than the main C thread, as long as you consistently call all GTK API functions from the same thread throughout the lifetime of the process. More details follow.

According to [the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html), GTK and GDK are not *thread-safe* (they cannot be concurrently called from multiple threads), but they are *thread-aware* — they provide locking functions such as `gdk_threads_enter` and `gdk_threads_leave` that can be used to synchronize GTK calls accross multiple threads. However, the documentation goes on to say that "with the Win32 backend, GDK and GTK+ calls should not be attempted from multiple threads at all." So, if you care about portability to Windows, you will want to avoid attempting to call GTK API calls from multiple threads. Additionally, GTK 3 completely deprecated the use of the threading locks.

There is, however, one way to safely call into GTK from multiple threads that works on all architectures: place the GTK calls in a function and pass it as callback to `g_idle_add` (without any special locking) — from any thread. It will schedule the callback to be invoked by the GTK main loop, in whatever thread is running it. This is documented at the end of the [description section](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html#gdk3-Threads.details) of the documentation, above the start of the [details section](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html#gdk3-Threads.details).

A word on terminology: the word "main thread" in C normally refers to the thread that runs the C `main()` function. In a GTK context, the "main thread" often confusingly refers to the thread running the GTK main loop. While the two can be (and typically are) one and the same, GTK doesn't really care what thread you call the main loop from, as long as you call all GTK functions (including `gtk_main`) from the same one. To avoid confusion, it is best to refer to this thread as the GTK thread, the main loop thread, or the GUI thread.

Comment: :: well thats a awsome explanation.But i have a strange performence in our GTK application..it runs very well in our Lenny(debian 5) but in squeeze (debiab 6) it runs well fro days but suddenly we see that our application GUI sudddenly fades out with white screen where we are able to see only the borders of button in the screen..still not able to find any clues on that.

Comment: @Ragav The fade-out means that your application is not responding to probe events sent by the desktop. You should use a debugger to find out what is blocking it; that (with additional details) might be material for a separate question.